# Javascript - DOM parser load ajax requests, scripts no run

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When a user clicks on a link instead of loading a whole new page I load the new page's HTML data through an ajax request (and also with a query string I get the server to not send the nav bar data each time) the resulting data from the ajax request I then put through DOMParser to allow me to just get the content from the div with the id of "content" and replace the current document's "context" div's innerHTML.

After doing a request through this method though any script tags within the newDOM don't run after being put in the content div. Also, it does appear to run while it is in newDOM either, because if you have a script that instantly edits the document while it loads there is no effect when you log out newDOM

```
AjaxRequest(href, function(data) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var newDOM = parser.parseFromString(data.responseText, "text/html");

  //Setup new title
  var title = '';
  if (newDOM.getElementsByTagName('title').length > 0 && newDOM.getElementsByTagName('title')[0] !== null) {
  title = newDOM.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
  } else {
  title = rawhref;
  }

  document.title = title;
  history.pushState({}, title, rawhref);

  if (newDOM.getElementById('content') === null) {
  //If there is an error message insert whole body into the content div to get full error message
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(newDOM.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
  } else {
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(newDOM.getElementById('content'));
  }

  MapDOM();

  if (typeof(onPageLoad) == "function") {
  onPageLoad();
  }
  });
```

Note: the variable "rawhref" is just the request URL without ?noheader so that it will be easier for users to go back though their history.
NOTE: Also after any new load I also have a function that overwrites any new a tag so that it will work though this method for the next new page.

Also, it would be much preferred if the answer didn't use jQuery.

Comment: you would need to call `eval()` on the _textContent_ of any newly added script tags.

Comment: @JaromandaX: You could use `Function` too i guess, or dataURLs, is that what you meant?

Comment: necessary? no, you could add dupe and add new scripts, but jQuery uses eval() for `load()` and even `html()`, and it should be faster than working with the slow dom...

Comment: `but jQuery uses` ... I have zero care factor for what jQuery uses :p

Comment: OK, but what about scripts with src attribute ... you HAVE to re-add those, eval wont help that

Comment: for sure. i'm just saying eval is shockingly widely acceptable in this specific context, due to it's existing wide-spread use and simplicity, even if nobody worth salt around here would publicly push _eval_...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some one just answered this and while I was testing it they deleted their solution.... Um, thanks so much who ever you were, and for anyone in the future who has this problem here is the code they showed, but I didn't have time to fully understand why it worked.... but I think can work it out.

```
function subLoader(dest, text) {
  var p = new DOMParser();
  var doc = p.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
  var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
  while (doc.body.firstChild) {
    f.appendChild(doc.body.firstChild);
  }
  [].map.call(f.querySelectorAll('script'), function(script) {
    var scriptParent = script.parentElement || f;
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    if (script.src) {
      newScript.src = script.src;
    } else {
      newScript.textContent = script.textContent;
    }
    scriptParent.replaceChild(newScript, script);
   });
   dest.appendChild(f);
}
```